# export a module function by some condition in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, module

```
module.exports ={
    "test1": {  
        moduleno: 1,
        modulename: 'test1'
    },

"test2": {  
    moduleno: 2,
    modulename: 'test2'
}
```

};

Guys I need a help, how can I do the following ? if condition1: export only test1 module else export test2 module.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how `if` statements work?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
const app = {};
module.exports = app;

app.moduleToExport = condition ? module1 : module2;
```

When you assign an object to `module.exports`, you're creating a new object on the fly. With this approach, you're also creating a new object but holding a reference to it in the variable app so that you can conditionally export a module or do any other logic that you need.

Answer (score 0):

LEt me suggest doind this:

```
   const app = {}

    app.test1 = {
        moduleno: 1,
        modulename: 'test1'
    }

    app.test2 = {
        moduleno: 2,
        modulename: 'test2'
    }

   //implement your condition in order to determine wich module to export
   //for example:
   const moduleToExport = 1 //Actually it may depends on some process 
   condition or another general condition
   const exported = moduleToExport === 1 ? app.test1:app.test2
   module.exports  = exported
```

I hope this helps